# How to change order of rendering in a React map

Tags: reactjs, graphql, conditional-rendering

I have a simple task and I feel the answer to this question is also simple. But for some reason I can't wrap my head around it. I'm supposed to get a list of questions from a database and display them on the site. This particular section is yes or no questions. When I get the questions from the database, most of them are already in order, "yes" and then "no". However, there's one that's flipped. So my question is, how do I flip the reversed one to its correct order?

I honestly haven't tried much because like I said, for some reason I can't wrap my head around it. But I do know that in the database the questions have a field called order where yes is 0 and no is 1. So I'm guessing I'll have to use that in some way.

Here's my code for rendering the questions,

```
{state.surveyQuestions.map(question => (
    <span key={question.question.id}>
        <FormLabel className={classes.label} component="legend">{question.question.label}</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup value={state.consent} onChange={handleChange} style={{ height: 'auto', padding: '10px' }}>
            {question.question.choices.items.map(choice => (
                <FormControlLabel key={choice.order} style={{ paddingTop: '1px' }} value={choice.value} control={<Radio />} label={choice.label} />
            ))}
        </RadioGroup>
    </span>
))}
```

and here's what's coming from the database,

```
"choices": {
    "items": [
        {
            "label": "No",
            "value": "{\"value\":\"0\"}",
            "dataUID": null,
            "description": "No",
            "order": 1,
            "goto": null
        },
        {
            "label": "Yes",
            "value": "{\"value\":\"1\"}",
            "dataUID": null,
            "description": "Yes",
            "order": 0,
            "goto": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.protoype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the 'choices' with a custom function;

```js
const data = [
    {
        "label": "No",
        "value": "{\"value\":\"0\"}",
        "dataUID": null,
        "description": "No",
        "order": 1,
        "goto": null
    },
    {
        "label": "Yes",
        "value": "{\"value\":\"1\"}",
        "dataUID": null,
        "description": "Yes",
        "order": 0,
        "goto": null
    }
];

// Full function for readability
function orderByOrderValue( a, b ) {
  if ( a.order < b.order ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.order > b.order ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(data.sort(orderByOrderValue));

// Or use the one-liner
// data.sort((a,b) => (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : ((b.id > a.id) ? -1 : 0));
```

Comment: Ah perfect. Just what I needed and makes perfect sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort with the `order` attribute of the choices i.e. `choices.items` when rendering the choices

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
```

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, sort a to an index    lower than b (i.e. a comes first).
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with    respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>   elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>   behavior, thus, not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back
>   to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index    lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

Following those rules, if you subtract the first appearing element's order with the following one you get the correct output for the sort function.